# Combine vectors of different dataframes to one list

Tags: r

I have three different data frames containing prices of different stocks with different length, as I had to remove outliers. The first column in each dataframe is always the date.

The next step is to combine the different columns of each dataframe into one list, especially to avoid pollution of my global environment and as I have to perform the same calculations (log-returns, etc) for each stock price.

1. How can I achieve this?
2. Is it preferable to have always a combination of date and returns for each stock that should constituent the list?

Here is the output.

```
head(Data)
A tibble: 6 x 11
    DATE     S1   S2   S3   S4 S5    S6 S7   S8     S9   
  <date>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2000-12-29 55.313 31.508 44.74 34.90 20.00 6.8470  7.49  55.5 25.7216
2 2001-01-01 55.313 31.508 44.74 34.90 20.00 6.8470  7.49  55.5 25.7216
3 2001-01-02 54.131 31.508 44.41 34.22 20.00 6.7793  7.24  55.4 25.5093
4 2001-01-03 52.641 31.806 45.70 34.53 20.00 6.7401  7.24  54.2 25.2652
5 2001-01-04 55.720 32.403 47.60 35.24 19.72 6.6697  7.20  55.3 26.3055
6 2001-01-05 57.607 32.502 46.50 37.69 21.02 6.7740  7.18  55.5 27.6006
# ... with 1 more variables: S10 <dbl>


#Elimnate Outliers from stock 2,3,10 and created shortened df for stock 8
Data1 <- Data[-c(2042:2046), -c(4:10) ] ; # eliminate outliers and not affected stocks
Data2 <- Data[-c(2972:4241),c(1,8)]; #stock price ends before others and eliminate all other stocks 
Data3 <- Data[,-c(2,3,7,11)] # Eliminate companies adjusted above
```

Here is what I have tried

```
Prices <- as.list(split(Data3,length(Data3)))
Prices <- append(split(Data1,length(Data1)),Prices)
Prices <- append(split(Data2,length(Data2)),Prices)
```

This gives me a list of three sublist, containing each df. But I would like to have only the vectors of Data1,Data2 and Data 3 as sublists. My final result should be list of 10 sublists (one for each stock).

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please? (input, code you tried and expected output)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.